# Showing sub-additivity of pre-measure $\mu_0(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}[a_i,b_i))=\sum_{i=1}^{N}F(b_i)-F(a_i)$ by Stieltjes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $F$ be a continuous from the right, monotonously increasing funtion (to $\Bbb{R}$), and let $A$ be the algebra of semi open intervals of the forms ($[a,b)$, with $a,b$ either being finite or non-finite).
Trying to prove that $\mu_0(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}[a_i,b_i))=\sum_{i=1}^{N}F(b_i)-F(a_i)$ for a collection of disjoint semi-open interval (which form an algebra) is a premeasure, I got stuck in an attempt to show that for a set of disjoint sets **$\{I_n\}, I_n\in A$** , it occurs that $\mu_0(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)\ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(I_n)$, **which I am asked to show** in a guided question, followed by an instruction to prove that second direction of this (in)equality.

I am not sure what I am supposed to show here, as it is followed by another question asking to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(I_n) \ge \mu_0(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n) $ given with instructions to use $\epsilon,\delta$ approximation, which should mean the first direction is probably simple, but what am I missing?

Because $\mu_0$ is only defined for finite union of sets, I don't know how to work with $I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$.

I would appreciate your ideas of this issue.